# Office 365 developer program

Tags: office-365, office-365-developer, office-dev-pnp

I am trying to enroll myself on "Office 365 developer program" via below link

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program

When I click on "Join Now" it gives me an option to select my preferences. Once I select those I got next screen which says below.

> ***Sign up for a free 12-month Office 365 developer subscription.***

My question is,

1. What will happen after 12 months?
2. Will I get an option to extend for another 12 months?
3. What are my options to keep the same tenant?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you can keep the subscription for 99$/year , according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/office-365-developer-program-faq

Answer (score 1):

1. Your subscriptions will be cancelled. If you do not extend them, [your data will be made inaccessible as if it was a regular tenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/subscriptions-and-billing/what-if-my-subscription-expires?view=o365-worldwide):
   [image]
2. Answered by Kasper. You have several price-reduced plans to extend subscriptions by your needs.
3. Please be careful when selecting the name of a DEV-Tenant. You might block names that are needed later in production. [You cannot delete or transform them!](https://blog.lawrencecawood.com/heres-what-happens-when-you-pick-the-wrong-office-365-tenant-name-27b657e8acbd). From my today's research i learned that a tenant also cannot be deleted.